# How to sketch a function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, multivariable-calculus

I want to scketch the following function

$$\varphi_s(q,p)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{\Large{-\frac{\Big(\cosh(s)q(s)+\sinh(s)p(s)\Big)^2+\Big(\sinh(s)q(s)+\cosh(s)p(s)\Big)^2}{2}}}$$ with $s\ge 0$

where the two axes are $q(t)$ and $p(t)$ for all $t\ge 0$

Thanks for your help

Comment: Where does this function come from?

Comment: this function satisfies \begin{align*}\frac{d}{ds}\varphi_s=(p\partial_q+q\partial_p)\varphi_s\end{align*} where $\Big(q(t),p(t)\Big)$ is the solution of

\begin{align*}
  \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
   \frac{d}{dt}q=p\\\\\  \frac{d}{dt}p=q\end{array}
\right.\end{align*}

Comment: What do you mean by sketching a function of two variables? Regardless, consider using some software (maple or mathematica) to do the work.

Comment: the two variables are $q(t)$ and $p(t)$, i nead a sketch with using some software (maple or mathematica), but i don't know how to use it, can you please help me? thanks